# How to parse field name with dash in snakeyaml?

Tags: java, field, snakeyaml

I have fragment of yaml file:

```
field-name: my/data
```

but I can't create pojo with method name `setField-name`

Is there any way to parse such yaml file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass a custom PropertyUtils to handle such cases

```
Constructor c = new Constructor(MyClass.class);
c.setPropertyUtils(new PropertyUtils() {
    @Override
    public Property getProperty(Class<? extends Object> type, String name) throws IntrospectionException {
      if ( name.indexOf('-') > -1 ) {
        name = toCameCase(name);
      }
      return super.getProperty(type, name);
    }
  });
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(c);
MyClass obj = (MyClass) yaml.load(input);
```

Comment: What the `toCamelCase` method came from?

Comment: You would have to implement that based on what is the corresponding property name that you need for that key