# Dump YAML File to Java Class with a field that contains a hyphen

Tags: java, snakeyaml

I'm attempting to dump a YAML File to a Java Class using SnakeYAML, but the field has hyphens in the name, and java variables cannot contain -.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391769/how-to-parse-field-name-with-dash-in-snakeyaml) answer regarding the subject, but there is no explanation as to what is happening or what the method `toCameName()` does.

**Yaml File**

```
field-with-hyphen: 1
```

**Goal**

```
public int fieldwithhypehen;
```

or whatever makes it so I can dump it.

Comment: In the linked question, `toCameName` is a misspelling of `toCamelCase`, a method that supposedly converts snake-case to CamelCase or lowerCamelCase. You'll have to use a library that provides similar functionality or implement it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Clashsoft for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to do some further research and construct the following method that transfers values with spaces and hyphens to camelCase.
`field-with-hyphens and spaces` turns into `fieldWithHyphensAndSpaces`

```
public class CamelCase {
    public static String camelize(String input) {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if(input.substring(i, i+1).equals("-")) {
                input.replace("-", "");
                input = input.substring(0, i) + input.substring(i+1, i+2).toUpperCase() + input.substring(i+2);
            }
            if(input.substring(i, i+1).equals(" ")) {
                input.replace(" ", "");
                input = input.substring(0, i) + input.substring(i+1, i+2).toUpperCase() + input.substring(i+2);
            }
        }
        return input;
    }
}
```

and implemented with SnakeYAML Parser (i tested it as well)

```
Constructor c = new Constructor(map);
c.setPropertyUtils(new PropertyUtils() {
    @Override
    public Property getProperty(Class<? extends Object> type, String name){
        if ( name.indexOf('-') > -1 ) {
            name = CamelCase.camelize(name);
        }
        return super.getProperty(type, name);
        }
    });
    parser = new Yaml(c);
    configFile = new File(FileConstants.getConfigDir() + relativePath);
}
```