# Serialize all properties to YAML as lowercase

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

So I have the following object:

```
public class Foo {

    private String firstName = "John";
    private String lastName = "Doe";

}
```

I want to serialize this class to YAML using SnakeYAML (not Jackson or using annotations) and make all properties lowercase like so:

```
firstname: John
lastname: Doe
```

I need to do this for a lot of classes, so I am looking for a generic way. Overriding PropertyUtils does not seem to work like in this case for parsing: [How to parse field name with dash in snakeyaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391769/how-to-parse-field-name-with-dash-in-snakeyaml)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if I understood your question correctly, but here is my solution:

```
Sample sample = new Sample(); // your class
        for(Field field : sample.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object value = field.get(sample);
            System.out.println(field.getName().toLowerCase() + " " + value.toString() + " " + field.getGenericType().getTypeName());
        }
```

for example, if you have a class like this:

```
public class Sample {
    
    String name = "John";
    String lastName = "Doe";
    int six = 6;
    
}
```

it will generate the following output:

```
name John java.lang.String
lastname Doe java.lang.String
six 6 int
```

you can then plug this into your YAML writer

Hope that answers it

Comment: The question was specific to the SnakeYAML Java library (it was in the title but removed, will edit the post)

Comment: Oh, didn’t see it there when I answered; I apologise